# "as.....as" structure when not making comparison

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

Below is part of a [recent article](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/06/23/opinion/trumps-lies.html) in the New York Times about Donald Trump's public lies.

> Many Americans have become accustomed to President Trump’s lies. But **as regular as** they have become, the country should not allow itself to become numb to them. So we have catalogued nearly every outright lie he has told publicly since taking the oath of office.

English is not my first language and I was wondering why the writer chose to come up with the clause "**as regular as** they have become" instead of "as they have become regular."

I'd like to know what the point of using the "**as ~ as**" structure would be when the writer didn't intend to make any comparison. Or is it a rhetorical expression? Or could it be a way of intensifying the meaning of the adjective "regular"?

Comment: Another way of saying roughly the same thing might be something like *even though they have become regular*

Comment: "...as regular as..." or "...so regular as..."?

Comment: @Dan I thought "so" went with negatives.

Comment: 'But as regular as they have become,' may also be paraphrased 'But in spite of the fact that they have become so regular,', though someone will probably have a fit over the use of 'the fact that'. But it's idiomatic.

Comment: Yes @EdwinAshworth, I think that is what is in the back of my mind!

Comment: Thank you @Edwin Ashworth. Your paraphrase is very helpful. But were you referring to the "as regular as they have become" part when you said it's idiomatic? Also, would it still make sense and mean the same if it is rewritten as "America should not allow itself to become numb to Trump's lies as much as they have become regular" or "America should not allow itself to become numb to Trump's lies as regular as they have become"?

Comment: I was referring to the immediate/closest candidate for the antecedent, as is normal: 'the fact that'. / I don't even like the original; I'd say that 'But with X's lies having become so regular, the country should take care that it does not become numb to them.' Your alternatives are at best unwieldy versions of the original.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for. Longman Dictionary says the "as ... as" construction is used to act like a "though" clause as in these examples: As popular as he is, the president hasn’t always managed to have his own way. / As smart as Jake is, he doesn't know how to manage people well. Thank you all for your kind advice. http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as

Comment: There’s still a comparison; it’s just not a comparison saying that X = Y in quality Z. In this usage where the comparison is more abstract, you can also leave out the first _as_: “Regular as they have become, the country should not allow itself to become numb to them”.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But the meaning you provide doesn't come in any way from this particular structure - and that's a problem. If the sentence were *but as regular as they have become, the country can only expect more lies to follow*, there would be no 'in spite of' slant. I find the notion of 'in spite of' to be completely jarring here. I was expecting the following sentence to take justification from "as regular as they have be come", not to use it as justification to counteract it. We have the handy word *despite* for setting that up.

Comment: @Phil Sweet I'm familiar with the 'As good as X is' meaning 'In spite of how good X is' usage. Here is an internet example: 'As good as he is he does not decide games by himself, although it sometimes looks like this...' [[news.com.au](http://www.news.com.au/sport/football/philippe-coutinho-liverpool-injury-news-brazilian-star-confirmed-to-be-out-until-2017/news-story/d37324dc7645d87e773273d19daa1b2e)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess I can't argue with that (or the Oxford Desk Dictionary and Thesaurus, which lists 'although' as def 2 for conj. as.) Perhaps me living in an area that tends towards negative concord makes this sound odd. I would use *although* or *despite* rather than *as* to set up this kind of backpedalling contrast, but Ngrams suggests that *although* is about a century out of date, and *despite* has only been used this way since 1960!.

Answer (score 1):

"As ___ as" can refer to a comparison, the OP indicates they are familiar with.

Alternatively, "as ___ as" can be used to refer to something clearly understood and as a recursive phrase to emphasize that it the characteristic is epitomized by the subject.

Consider the following examples that use the phrase as recursive emphasis:

"As tall as Abraham Lincoln was, he would often bend over when walking through doorways."

"As smart as he is, it's strange that he made such a bad decision."

Comment: It's still a comparison, used adverbially (the result of the comparison is still an adjective quality).  "[being] tall (as we all known Lincoln was), he would often bend over ..."

Answer (score 0):

The [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/06/23/opinion/trumps-lies.html) you mention has listed a ton of lies from Trump, and Americans are becoming numb to it.

The author is comparing the regularness of Trump's lies and that of being numb to those lies.

So, in essence, the author is saying, the country becoming numb to Trumps's lies should not be as regular a thing as Trump saying those lies.

Or, in other words, even though Trump's lies have become a regular thing, it should not become a regular thing for the country to become numb to those lies.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I know what you're trying to explain but I still don't think I have a better grasp of the structure. I know it takes more than words to construct a sentence but this one is tough.

Comment: @ChoeGuevara I see. What more explanation are you looking for?